# Unscented Kalman Filter - How should I interpret the math of UKF?

Tags: control-theory, parameter-estimation, optimal-control, kalman-filter

I need some help for explaining the Unscented Kalman Filter (UKF). I understand regular Kalman Filter and Extended Kalman Filter, which is the same as regular Kalman Filter after the linearization.

First I'm going to write down that UKF algorithm and for every equation I write down, I will ask a question.

**Step 1:**

First initilize the estimated state vector $\hat x[k-1]$ and covariance matrix $P[k-1]$ with with:

$$\hat x[k-1] = E(x[k])$$
$$P[k-1] = E(x[k] - \hat x[k-1])(x[k] - \hat x[k-1])^T $$

**Question 1:**

- Is it OK if I assume that the average of steady state output measurement $\bar y[k]$ can be assumed as average $E(x[k])$ and there fore $\hat x[k-1] = \bar y[k]$ as the beginning?
- $\hat x[k-1]$ is described as best initial guess before measurement, so what should $x[k]$ be then?

**Step 2:**

Now we need to talk about sigma points $\hat x^{(i)}[k-1]$. I begin first to say that sigma point `0` is:

$$\hat x^{(0)}[k-1] = \hat x[k-1]$$

The rest of the sigma points $\hat x^{(i)}[k-1]$ get its values from:

$$\hat x^{(i)}[k-1] = \hat x[k-1] + \Delta x^{(i)}, i = 1...2M$$
$$\Delta x^{(i)} = (\sqrt{cP[k-1]})_{(i)}, i = 1...M$$
$$\Delta x^{(i+M)} = -(\sqrt{cP[k-1]})_{(i)}, i = 1...M$$

Where $c$ is a scalar $c = \alpha^2(M+\kappa)$, where $M$ is number of states, e.g dimension of state vector $x[k]$ and $\kappa$ and $\alpha$ are tuning parameters of free choice. Normally $\alpha$ is a positive but very smal number and $\kappa$ is usually `0`.

**Question 2:**

- Declaring the first sigma points as the estimated state vector $\hat x^{(0)}[k-1] = \hat x[k-1]$ is easy, but how do I get the rest of the sigma points? I'm talking about the equation like this $(\sqrt{cP[k-1]})_{(i)}$
- $P[k-1]$ is a matrix and takin the square root of a matrix like this $(\sqrt{cP[k-1]})_{(i)}$ does not create a vector $\Delta x^{(i)}$...or does it?

**Step 3:**

For all kalman filters, we need to have a dynamical model. Assume that here it is:

$$x[k+1] = f(x[k], u[k])$$
$$y[k] = h(x[k], u[k])$$

Where $u[k]$ is the input signal, $y[k]$ is the model output measurement, $h()$ is the measurement function and $f()$ is the dynamical system. So the task must be where I'm using my sigma points as the state vector for $h()$ for compute the output sigma points $\hat y^{(i)}[k]$

$$\hat y^{(i)}[k-1] = h(\hat x^{(i)}[k-1], u_m[k]), i = 0...2M$$

**Question 3:**

- Most if the time, I don't have a measurement function $h()$ and only a dynamical system $f()$. Is it OK to find the estimated output if my model looks like this instead? I'm using [SINDy algorithm](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid) and it can identify a nonlinear state space model $f()$ from data. I recommend it all over linear system identification.
- What is $u_m[k]$?

**Step 4:**

Now when I got the output sigma points $\hat y^{(i)}[k]$, then I must find the estimated output $\hat y[k]$.

$$\hat y[k] = \sum^{2M}_{i=0}W^{(i)}_M \hat y^{(i)}[k-1]$$
$$W^{(0)}_M = 1 - \frac{M}{\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}$$
$$W^{(i)}_M = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}, i = 1...2M$$

**Question 4:**

- Where is the index of $\frac{M}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}$ ? I don't see any $i$ here.

**Step 5:**

Now we need to find the covariance matrix for output $P_y$

$$P_y =  \sum^{2M}_{i=0}W^{(i)}_c(\hat y^{(i)}[k-1] - \hat y[k])(\hat y^{(i)}[k-1] - \hat y[k])^T + R[k]$$
$$W^{(0)}_c = 2 - \alpha^2 + \beta - \frac{M}{\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}$$
$$W^{(i)}_c = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}, i = 1...2M$$

Where $\beta$ is a tuning parameter, for gausian distribution and $2$ of optimal knowledge about the state vectors.

**Question 5:**

- How can i find $R[k]$?

**Step 6:**

Compute a covariance matrix $P_{xy}$

$$P_{xy} = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)} \sum^{2M}_{i=1}W^{(i)}_c(\hat x^{(i)}[k-1] - \hat x[k-1])(\hat y^{(i)}[k-1] - \hat y[k])^T$$

Notice that we need to start at $i = 1$.

**Question 6:**

- No question

**Step 7:**

Now it's time to find the kalman gain $K$.

$$K = P_{xy} P^{-1}_y$$
$$\hat x[k] = \hat x[k-1] + K(y[k] - \hat y[k])$$
$$P[k] = P[k-1] - KP_yK^T_k$$

**Question 7:**

- What is $K^T_k$? I know that it's the transpose of $K_k$, but where does $k$ comes from?`
- Finding the inverse $P^{-1}$ is not effective. Do you recommend an algorithm to solve $K$ from $KP_y = P_{xy}$?

**Step 8:**

Now when we have your current estimated state $\hat x[k]$ from previous estimated state $\hat x[k-1]$. We are going to to predict the future estimated state $\hat x[k+1]$.

$$\hat x^{(0)}[k] = \hat x[k]$$
$$\hat x^{(i)}[k] = \hat x[k] + \Delta x^{(i)}, i = 1...2M$$
$$\Delta x^{(i)} = (\sqrt{cP[k]})_{(i)}, i = 1...M$$
$$\Delta x^{(i+M)} = -(\sqrt{cP[k]})_{(i)}, i = 1...M$$

**Question 8:**

- No question

**Step 9:**

Compute the predicted sigma points from our dynamical model.

$$\hat y^{(i)}[k+1] = f(\hat x^{(i)}[k+1], u_s[k]), i = 0...2M$$

**Question 9:**

- What is $u_s[k]$?

**Step 10:**

Compute these. I don't know why...

$$\hat x[k+1] = \sum^{2M}_{i=0}W^{(i)}_M \hat x^{(i)}[k+1]$$
$$W^{(0)}_M = 1 - \frac{M}{\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}$$
$$W^{(i)}_M = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}, i = 1...2M$$

**Question 10:**

- No question

**Step 11:**

Compute this and then you're done.

$$P[k+1] =  \sum^{2M}_{i=0}W^{(i)}_c(\hat x^{(i)}[k+1] - \hat x[k+1])(\hat x^{(i)}[k+1] - \hat x[k+1])^T + Q[k]$$
$$W^{(0)}_c = 2 - \alpha^2 + \beta - \frac{M}{\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}$$
$$W^{(i)}_c = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}, i = 1...2M$$

**Question 11:**

- How do I get $Q[k]$?

---

Now we have the next covariance matrix $P[k+1]$ and next estimated state vector $\hat x[k+1]$. That means when we jump back to **Step 2** again, then $P[k]$ and $\hat x[k]$ is becoming $P[k-1]$ and $\hat x[k-1]$ and the current $P[k-1]$ and $\hat x[k-1]$ will no longer be useful for us becaue the becomes $P[k-2]$ and $\hat x[k-2]$

Our goal is to find the state $\hat x[k]$.

Equations can be found at [MathWorks: Extended and Unscented Kalman Filter Algorithms for Online State Estimation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/extended-and-unscented-kalman-filter-algorithms-for-online-state-estimation.html)

Please correct me if I'm wrong or wrote some errors in the math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1.** You mean $\hat{x}[0]$ and $P[0]$? They are just guesses. You can use your first measurement for $\hat{x}[0]$ and give a possible error value $P[0]$ depending on your measurement accuracy. $k$ starts from 1.

**Question 2.** You use the $i$th column of the matrix.

**Question 3.** You have to have an $h$, maybe it is just the identity function and you measure all the states? $u_m[k]$ is just the input, they just give a different name for unknown reasons I think.

**Question 4.** These choice of weights are independent from the index.

**Question 5.** $R[k]$ is the covariance of the measurement error. You can use the accuracy knowledge of the measurement device to determine it.

**Question 7.** $k$ is just a typo. You can use something like the LU decomposition to solve for $K$. But generally the number of outputs are small, so $P_y$ is a small square matrix.

**Question 9.** $u_s[k]$ is just the input.

**Question 11.** $Q[k]$ is the process noise covariance, which is something you know as in the linear KF.

I believe Wikipedia has a good explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Unscented_Kalman_filter

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I like it. In this case, $P$ is diagonal? I assume that because I'm going to take square root of $P$.

Comment: It only needs to be symmetric. It is defined in the link you gave. Also see Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: Thank you. I'm writing C code for UKF. I have some trouble to take the inverse of $P$ even if it's symmetric. Why? According to the papers, I should do that.

Comment: You mean inverse of $P_y$? First of all it must be symmetric. If you select invertible $R$ it should also be invertible. Otherwise there is probably some error in the code.

Comment: Thank you! And one more question. Is $M$ the number of states as in state vectors or just the dimension of the state vector?

Comment: The dimension of the state vector

Comment: So if I have a state vector of the dimension 2, then I would have 2*2 + 1 = 5 sigma points?

Comment: Hi! Again! I have written the C-code for UKF now, but I have some issues. Can $P_y$ have positive values at the diagonal and negative at the other elements of the matrix? I get the same issue with $P$ matrix. It contains some negative values as well. Bad for `sqrt`. Do you want the C-code?

Comment: This creates issues if $P$ contains negative values on the side. $P$ does not have negative values on the diagonal. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/5f3a25dc9ac52b015a3ac9c2719ee27da07e0692/src/CControl/Sources/Filtering/ukf.c#L161

Comment: Square root of a matrix is not the square root of individual elements. It is the Cholesky decomposition in this context. This is also defined in the link you gave in the question.

Comment: Ok! But I thought $P$ was symmetric and therefore I could take `sqrt` of every element. So you are saying that my `cholesky` decomposition function have some issues? I have tried to solve `Ax=b` with cholelsky where `A` is symmetric and positive definitive and it works.

Comment: Even if $P$ is symmetric you cannot take square root of every element to find the Cholesky decomposition. If you are using this method to solve $Ax=b$ I doubt that it works. I think it is wise to compare the solution with another solver.

Comment: So how can I find the matrix square root? Is it by using cholesky decomposition?

Comment: Actually solving $K = P_{xy}P_y^{-1}$ can be done by using $Ax=b$ where $A = P_y$ and $b$ is every column `i` from $P_{xy}$. In `MATLAB` use `xi = linsolve(A, B(:, i))` where $A$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix and $B$ is a matrix. When you haveing all the $X = x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots , x_i$ then you have solved $K$

Comment: By the way! I did open a new question about an issue where $P$ become non positive definite. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170831/why-does-covariance-p-matrix-become-non-positive-definite-in-unscented-kalman