# Why does covariance $P$ matrix become non positive definite in Unscented Kalman Filter?

Tags: control-theory, covariance, optimal-control, kalman-filter

I'm doing Unscented Kalman Filter in MATLAB code and I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/extended-and-unscented-kalman-filter-algorithms-for-online-state-estimation.html) how to create one.

First I initilize the $\hat x$ vector and covariance $P$ matrix first. In MATLAB code, I just set them into random numbers.

$$\hat x[k-1] = E(x[k])$$
$$P[k-1] = E(x[k] - \hat x[k-1])(x[k] - \hat x[k-1])^T $$

Then I compute the sigma points $\hat x^{(i)}$

MATLAB code: `[xhati] = ukf_compute_sigma_points(xhat, P, a, k, row);`

$$\hat x^{(0)}[k-1] = \hat x[k-1]$$
$$\hat x^{(i)}[k-1] = \hat x[k-1] + \Delta x^{(i)}, i = 1...2M$$
$$\Delta x^{(i)} = (\sqrt{cP[k-1]})_{(i)}, i = 1...M$$
$$\Delta x^{(i+M)} = -(\sqrt{cP[k-1]})_{(i)}, i = 1...M$$

Then I'm using the observation function $y = h(x, u)$ with the current sigma point $x^{(i)}$. In this case, I say that $y = x$

MATLAB code: `yhati = xhati;`

$$\hat y^{(i)}[k-1] = h(\hat x^{(i)}[k-1], u[k]), i = 0...2M$$

Then I compute the estimated $\hat y$ vector.

MATLAB code: `yhat = ukf_multiply_weights(yhati, WM, M);`

$$\hat y[k] = \sum^{2M}_{i=0}W^{(i)}_M \hat y^{(i)}[k-1]$$
$$W^{(0)}_M = 1 - \frac{M}{\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}$$
$$W^{(i)}_M = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}, i = 1...2M$$

I compute the covariance matrix $P_y$.

MATLAB code: `Py = ukf_estimate_covariance(yhati, yhat, Wc, R, row);`

$$P_y =  \sum^{2M}_{i=0}W^{(i)}_c(\hat y^{(i)}[k-1] - \hat y[k])(\hat y^{(i)}[k-1] - \hat y[k])^T + R[k]$$
$$W^{(0)}_c = 2 - \alpha^2 + \beta - \frac{M}{\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}$$
$$W^{(i)}_c = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}, i = 1...2M$$

Cross covariance matrix $P_{xy}$.

MATLAB code: `Pxy = ukf_estimate_cross_covariance(xhati, xhat, yhati, yhat, a, k, M);`

$$P_{xy} = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)} \sum^{2M}_{i=1}W^{(i)}_c(\hat x^{(i)}[k-1] - \hat x[k-1])(\hat y^{(i)}[k-1] - \hat y[k])^T$$

I compute kalman gain matrix $K$ by using Cholesky decomposition for every column of $P_{xy}$.

$$L^TL = P_y$$
$$Ly = P_{xy}(:, i), i = 1...M$$
$$L^Tx = y$$
$$K(:, i) = x, i = 1...M$$

MATLAB code: `K = ukf_create_kalman_K(Py, Pxy, M);`

$$K = P_{xy} P^{-1}_y$$

I do state update and covaraince $P$ update as well.

MATLAB code: `[xhat, P] = ukf_state_update(K, Py, P, xhat, y, yhat, M);`

$$\hat x[k] = \hat x[k-1] + K(y[k] - \hat y[k])$$
$$P[k] = P[k-1] - KP_yK^T_k$$

Now I'm computing the sigma points again because now I'm going to predict the future states. Notice that I DON'T take $\sqrt{cP}$. Instead I assume that $L$ from $L^TL = cP$ is the square root of $cP$ where $c$ is a scalar. The [authors](https://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Ewelch/kalman/media/pdf/Julier1997_SPIE_KF.pdf) of Unscented Kalman Filter did that assumption.

> The sigma points capture the same mean and covariance irrespective of
> the choice of matrix square root which is used. Numerically efficient
> and stable methods such as the Cholesky decomposition[18] can be used.

MATLAB code: `xhati = ukf_compute_sigma_points(xhat, P, a, k, M);`

$$\hat x^{(0)}[k] = \hat x[k]$$
$$\hat x^{(i)}[k] = \hat x[k] + \Delta x^{(i)}, i = 1...2M$$
$$\Delta x^{(i)} = (\sqrt{cP[k]})_{(i)}, i = 1...M$$
$$\Delta x^{(i+M)} = -(\sqrt{cP[k]})_{(i)}, i = 1...M$$

Mow I'm suing the transition function with the new sigma points $\hat x^{(i)}$ to get the future $\hat x^{(i)}$.

In this case the transition function is
$$\dot x_1 = -2x_1x_2 + 4x_2 + 4u_1$$
$$\dot x_2 = -x_1 - 3x_2 + 7u_2$$

MATLAB code: `xhati = ukf_transition(xhati, u, M);`

$$\hat x^{(i)}[k+1] = f(\hat x^{(i)}[k], u_s[k]), i = 0...2M$$

And I compute the estimated states.

MATLAB code: `xhat = ukf_multiply_weights(xhati, WM, M);`

$$\hat x[k+1] = \sum^{2M}_{i=0}W^{(i)}_M \hat x^{(i)}[k+1]$$
$$W^{(0)}_M = 1 - \frac{M}{\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}$$
$$W^{(i)}_M = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}, i = 1...2M$$

And last I update the covariance matrix $P$, which will NOT become positive definite. That's the issue with my code and I don't know why.

$$P[k+1] =  \sum^{2M}_{i=0}W^{(i)}_c(\hat x^{(i)}[k+1] - \hat x[k+1])(\hat x^{(i)}[k+1] - \hat x[k+1])^T + Q[k]$$
$$W^{(0)}_c = 2 - \alpha^2 + \beta - \frac{M}{\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}$$
$$W^{(i)}_c = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2(M+\kappa)}, i = 1...2M$$

**Question:**

When running this MATLAB code. why does covariance $P$ get this covariance matrix.

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
-0.028857  & -0.583326 \\
  -0.583326 &  2.546039
\end{bmatrix}$$

At the function

`[xi] = ukf_compute_sigma_points(x, P, a, k, M)`

We can clearly see that $P$ is not positive definite. Why?

**My theory.**

If you look at the code `[xhat, P] = ukf_state_update(K, Py, P, xhat, y, yhat, M)`

You can clearly see this statement `P = P - K*Py*K';` I did try to change the transpose to `P = P - K'*Py*K;` and now the code is working. But is this correct way? What do you think?
I have also a textbook about UFK where this line is used with $P$ instead of $P_y$

`P = P - K*P*K';`

I also made a C-code version [here](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Sources/Filtering/ukf.c).

Here is my complete MATLAB code.

```
function ukf_test()
  % Initial states
  y = [0; 0];
    u = [1; 2];
    xhat = [0; 0];
    P = [5  0; 0 2];
    Q = [1, 0; 0, 2];
    R = [1.5, 0; 0, 2];
    a = 1;
    k = 2;
    b = 3;
  M = 2;
  for i = 1:2
    [xhat, y, P] = ukf(xhat, y, u, P, Q, R, a, k, b, M);
  end
end

function [xhat, y, P] = ukf(xhat, y, u, P, Q, R, a, k, b, M)
  column = 2 * M + 1;
  row = M;
  
  % Step 0 - Create the weights
  [WM, Wc] = ukf_create_weights(a, b, k, row);
  
  % UPDATE: Step 1 - Compute sigma points
  [xhati] = ukf_compute_sigma_points(xhat, P, a, k, row);
  
  % UPDATE: Step 2 - Use the nonlinear measurement function to compute the predicted measurements for each of the sigma points.
  yhati = xhati; % Here we assume that the observation function y = h(x, u) = x
  
  % UPDATE: Step 3 - Combine the predicted measurements to obtain the predicted measurement
  yhat = ukf_multiply_weights(yhati, WM, M);
  
  % UPDATE: Step 4 - Estimate the covariance of the predicted measurement
  Py = ukf_estimate_covariance(yhati, yhat, Wc, R, row);
  
  % UPDATE: Step 5 - Estimate the cross-covariance between xhat and yhat. Here i begins at 1 because xhati(0) - xhat(0) = 0
  Pxy = ukf_estimate_cross_covariance(xhati, xhat, yhati, yhat, a, k, M);
  
  % UPDATE: Step 6 - Find kalman K matrix
    K = ukf_create_kalman_K(Py, Pxy, M);
  
  % UPDATE: Step 7 - Obtain the estimated state and state estimation error covariance at time step
  [xhat, P] = ukf_state_update(K, Py, P, xhat, y, yhat, M);
  
  % PREDICT: Step 0 - Predict the state and state estimation error covariance at the next time step
    xhati = ukf_compute_sigma_points(xhat, P, a, k, M);

    % PREDICT: Step 1 - Use the nonlinear state transition function to compute the predicted states for each of the sigma points.
    xhati = ukf_transition(xhati, u, M);

    % PREDICT: Step 2 - Combine the predicted states to obtain the predicted states at time
    xhat = ukf_multiply_weights(xhati, WM, M);

    % PREDICT: Step 3 - Compute the covariance of the predicted state
    P = ukf_estimate_covariance(xhati, xhat, Wc, Q, M);
  
end

function [WM, Wc] = ukf_create_weights(a, b, k, M)
  column = 2 * M + 1;
  WM = zeros(1, column);
  Wc = zeros(1, column);
  for i = 1:column
    if(i == 1)
      Wc(i) = (2 - a * a + b) - M / (a * a * (M + k));
      WM(i) = 1 - M / (a * a * (M + k));
    else
      Wc(i) = 1 / (2 * a * a * (M + k));
      WM(i) = 1 / (2 * a * a * (M + k));
    end
  end
end

function [xi] = ukf_compute_sigma_points(x, P, a, k, M)
  column = 2 * M + 1;
    compensate_column = 2 * M - 1;
    row = M;
    c = a * a * (M + k);
  xi = zeros(row, column);
  
    % According to the paper "A New Extension of the Kalman Filter to Nonlinear Systems"
    % by Simon J. Julier and Jeffrey K. Uhlmann, they used L = chol(c*P) as "square root",
    % instead of computing the square root of c*P. According to them, cholesky decomposition
    % was a numerically efficient and a stable method.
  L = chol(c*P, 'lower');

  for j = 1:column
    if(j == 1)
      xi(:, j) = x;
    elseif(and(j >= 2, j <= row + 1))
      xi(:, j) = x + L(:, j - 1);
    else 
      xi(:, j) = x - L(:, j - compensate_column);
    end
  end
  
end

function x = ukf_multiply_weights(xi, W, M)
  column = 2 * M + 1;
    row = M;
  x = zeros(row, 1);
  for i = 1:column
    x = x + W(i)*xi(:, i);
  end
end

function P = ukf_estimate_covariance(xi, x, W, O, M)
  column = 2 * M + 1;
    row = M;
  P = zeros(row, row);
  for i = 1:column
    P = P + W(i)*(xi(:, i) - x)*(xi(:, i) - x)';
  end
  P = P + O;
end

function P = ukf_estimate_cross_covariance(xi, x, yi, y, a, k, M)
    column = 2 * M + 1;
    row = M;
  c = 1 / (2 * a * a * (M + k));
  P = zeros(row, row);
  for i = 2:column % Begins at 2 because xi(:, 1) - x = 0
    P = P + (xi(:, i) - x)*(yi(:, i) - y)';
  end
  P = c*P;
end

function K = ukf_create_kalman_K(Py, Pxy, M)
  row = M;
  K = zeros(row, row);
  for i = 1:row
    % Solve Ax = b with Cholesky
    L = chol(Py, 'lower');
    y = linsolve(L, Pxy(:, i));
    K(:, i) = linsolve(L', y);
  end
  % This will work to K = linsolve(Py, Pxy);
end

function [xhat, P] = ukf_state_update(K, Py, P, xhat, y, yhat, M)
    row = M;
  xhat = xhat + K*(y - yhat);
  P = P - K*Py*K';
end

function xhati = ukf_transition(x, u, M)
  column = 2 * M + 1;
  row = M;
  xhati = zeros(row, column);
  for i = 1:column
     xhati(:, i) = transistion_function(x(:, i), u);
  end 
end

function dx = transistion_function(x, u)
  dx = zeros(2, 1);
  dx(1) = -2*x(1)*x(2) + 4*x(2) + 4*u(1);
  dx(2) = -x(1) - 3*x(2) + 7*u(2);
end
```

Comment: compensate_column in ukf_compute_sigma_points must be $M+1$ I believe.

Comment: @obareey Yes you are right! The reason is that I first wrote the C code, then translated the C code to MATLAB code directly. But still, even if `compensate_column = M+1;` I still get `P` to become a non positive definite matrix.